# Trying to understand a negative correlation in a coin toss experiment

Tags: regression, correlation

I draw $n$ coins from an infinite pool of biased coins with head probabilities uniformly distributed between 0.1 to 0.9. The (true) biases of the $n$ coins are summarized in a vector $b$.

On each coin, I perform two independent experiments, in each of which the coin is tossed $m$ times in order to compute an estimate of the bias. As a result I have two vectors, $\hat{b}_1$ and $\hat{b}_2$ which represent the estimated biases of the coins for experiment 1 and experiment 2, respectively.

Now I am computing the correlation $corr\left(\hat{b}_1, \frac{b}{\hat{b}_2}\right)$ and I observe a small, but highly significant (with a high enough $n$) correlation. I am trying to understand how the correlation comes about. Is it possible to explain the emergence of this correlation (intuitively or mathematically)?

By contrast, none of the correlations $corr\left(\hat{b}_1, \frac{\hat{b}_2}{b}\right)$, $corr\left(\hat{b}_1, b-\hat{b}_2\right)$ or $corr\left(\hat{b}_1, \hat{b}_2-b\right)$ are significant.

Python code, for convenience:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

n_coins = 100000  # n
ntosses_per_coin = 1000  # m
true_bias = 0.1 + 0.8 * np.random.rand(n_coins, 1)
estimated_bias1 = (true_bias > np.random.rand(n_coins, ntosses_per_coin)).mean(axis=1)
estimated_bias2 = (true_bias > np.random.rand(n_coins, ntosses_per_coin)).mean(axis=1)

print(pearsonr(estimated_bias1, true_bias.squeeze() / estimated_bias2))
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this correlation and why you compute it?  It involves a *vector* $\hat b_1$ of *estimates* and the *quotient* of two other vectors.  That admits a great many different interpretations of "correlation," depending on whether one is computing a sample correlation, an empirical value, or some hybrid.

Comment: Sample correlation. The problem is simplified and abstracted away from another issue I'm trying to resolve. In brief, two measures which can be boiled down to $\hat{b}_1$ and $\frac{b}{\hat{b}_2}$ are claimed to be independent when computed in a cross-validated way (hence the 2 experiments). Clearly, the cross-validation is contaminated by $b$, which underlies both $\hat{b}_1$  and $\hat{b}_2$. I'm not clear though, why this contamination shows up as a significant correlation specifically for $corr\left(\hat{b}_1, \frac{b}{\hat{b}_2}\right)$ and for none of the other 3 mentioned correlations.

Comment: "Independent" in this sense is not assessed by computing the correlation coefficient.  It must refer to the independence, under the sampling distributions, of the two *random variables* $\hat b_1$ and $b/\hat b_2.$